# #pragma compilation Error

Tags: compilation

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract test {
    event test_value(uint256 indexed value1);
    uint256 value_test;

     function test_f()  {

        //value_test processing
        test_value(value_test); // log the current value
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am getting following error while compiling through Remix:

> browser/ballot_test.sol:1:1: SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version

Answer (score 0):

I used ^0.5.1 in the #pragma directive and this solved my problem.

Zulfi.